# Css display: none works half way

Tags: css

I have following css and display is set to none if there are no records. However, it displays a red line at the top. You can verify it here http://jsfiddle.net/3agn58u4. Any idea what is causing this?

CSS:

```
<style>

body {
    font-family:Calibri;
}
#customTaskNotification {
    position:relative;


}
.TasksCount {
    position:absolute;
    top: -.1px; 
    right:-.1px;
    padding:1px 2px 1px 2px;
    background-color:#ff0000; /* orange #ef8913* dark-pink #d06079 */
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.05em;
    width:50%;
    text-align: center;

    border-radius:50%!important;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 1px gray;
}

div.TasksCount:empty { 
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your CSS, and the display: none isn't actually taking effect.

Comment: If you look at far right in the result window you will see what I am talking about. <div class="TasksCount">
    <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/">TEST</a> 
</div>

Comment: what's the :empty for? I removed it and the red line does go away. http://jsfiddle.net/3agn58u4/1/

Comment: Precisely - your display: none isn't taking effect because your div is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `TasksCount` background color is set to red. You can set the `padding:0` if you want to keep the same color. Or,

```
.TasksCount {
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

**EDIT**

This answer has been downvoted multiple times because it does not answer the real question :

Why the `:empty` property is not taking effect.

As others pointed out, this CSS property matches only elements that have no children. This is the correct answer to this question.

The OP asked

> "However, it displays a red line at the top. You can verify it here
>   ... Any idea what is causing this?"

I missed the point about the empty property and did suggested first to remove the padding which partially solves the 'red line' when the DIV and its children are empty. However, this will also strip the padding from the element when it has content.

If you think you have a more complete answer to this question , please leave a comment below and I will update it accordingly.

Comment: Try adding a working sample to your answer. Otherwise, it looks like a comment

Comment: That's exactly the answer to the OP's question. He wants to get rid of the red line which is caused by the background-color .

Comment: That is totally missing the point. You can also get rid of the red by deleting all the CSS but that doesn't mean that's the solution. His problem is that he's expecting the `:empty` CSS properties to apply when the div isn't actually empty.

Comment: @leigero Yes, you are right. I missed the point and did not pay attention for the empty property. Thanks

Comment: I disagree.  For the one who knows, the answer is obvious.  For the one learning (i.e. the OP who is stumped) and all others who visit the question later, added clarity and working code samples are beneficial

Comment: @raja.khoury Thanks for your help. it worked in first try. I appreciate it.

Comment: @leigero No prob man although it does not answer your question I am glad it helps somehow

Comment: This isn't the answer, Shawn, and shouldn't be marked as such.

Comment: @leigero: Now I just feel bad for raja. His answer has been held hostage thanks to a decision by a wilfully ignorant asker, and will continue collecting downvotes for as long as it doesn't address the question.

Comment: @BoltClock Hi, I did my update the answer for future visitors : Is there anything else I should have included ? Thanks

Comment: @raja.khoury: I think it should be fine now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're trying to set CSS styling on a property based on it being `empty` but that div is not actually empty.

You can see in the snippet provided that the `:empty` selector is not going to apply to a `<div>` element that isn't actually empty (even if you can't see its contents).

```css
.testDiv {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.testDiv:empty { 
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
    <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/"></a> 
</div>

<div class="testDiv"></div>

<div class="testDiv">
</div>
```

You may need Javascript to check actual content of a div before applying styles if this case is going to be prevalent in your solution.

You can change the padding of your `<div>` and yes, that will hide it from your view when the contents of the div aren't visible, but you're also removing the padding from your `<div>` so it's likely going to look bad (or not as desired) when there are actual links inside the div.

Comment: I want to upvote this answer, but on the other hand I'm considering closing and deleting the question as it's low quality anyway. In fact, I totally would have done that sooner, had I known the OP was going to stubbornly ignore all of the correct answers - as well as my comments.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes I agree. I noticed the poster of the accepted answer is making a good faith effort to make the answer a better quality, so at least there's that.

Answer (score 3):

The `:empty` pseudo selector will select elements that

- contain nothing
- or every element that has no children (including text nodes).
- or matches element that is empty but has only html comments.

Example:

```
<p></p><!-- empty element -->
<p>A paragraph.</p><!-- contains text,hence not an empty element -->
<p><!-- test --></p><!-- empty element with comment -->
<p>A paragraph.</p><!-- contains text,hence not an empty element -->
<p><a></a></p><!-- element has no text,but has child nodes,hence not empty -->
<p>A paragraph.</p><!-- contains text,hence not an empty element -->
<p> </p><!-- element has space ,hence not empty -->
```

please see the fiddle:[EMPTY ELEMENT](http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/kj8rhrky/2/)

This is the reason why your display none is not working.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_empty.asp):

> The :empty selector matches every element that has no children
>   (including text nodes).

`TasksCount` is not empty because it has a child(`a` element) so `display:none;` does not effect. By css, it is not possible to check the child where is empty or not and then select parent.

Solution: use Javascript or Jquery.

```
if($('.TasksCount').find('a').html() == ''){
    //Or you can add class or add style $('.TasksCount').css('display','none');
    $('.TasksCount').hide();
}
```